# Variable '${username}' not found while using Robot Framework with DataDriver library

Tags: robotframework

I'm new in Robot Framework, and now get stuck while using DataDriver library in my robot script.

My problem:
There is a message : "Variable '${username}' not found." while I run the robot script and the test was FAIL.

This is my robot script:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  DataDriver  file=resources/user_password.csv  encoding=utf_8  dialect=unix
Test Template  Test Credential

*** Test Cases ***
Doing Test Credentials for ${username} and ${password}

*** Keywords ***
Test Credential
    [Arguments]     ${username}     ${password}
    Log  ${username}
    Log  ${password}
```

and this is my CSV file:

```
*** Test Cases ***, ${username}, ${password}, [Tags], [Documentation]
Valid user, user@mail.com, pass123, Positive, This is valid user credential
Invalid user, invalid@mail.com, pass123, Negative, This user is invalid
Invalid password, user@mail.com, pass, Negative, This password is invalid
Blank user, ${EMPTY}, pass123, Negative, Blank user
Blank password, user@mail.com, ${EMPTY}, Negative, Blank password
Blank user and password, ${EMPTY}, ${EMPTY}, Negative, Blank both user and password
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Welly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Doing Test Credentials for ${username} and ${password}
```

You're not passing any variables to the keyword as it's shown in the documentation for the DataDriver library: https://github.com/Snooz82/robotframework-datadriver#example-test-suite

A solution would be to pass some values to the keyword:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Doing Test Credentials for ${username} and ${password}    secret-user    secret-pwd
```

**EDIT:**

Another is the format of your csv file. You include spaces after each comma, if I delete them:

```
*** Test Cases ***,${username},${password},[Tags],[Documentation]
Valid user,user@mail.com,pass123,Positive,This is valid user credential
```

I can run it without any problems:

[image]

and the report:

[image]

Comment: I have add this 'secret-user  secret-pwd' in that line, and the message is the same.

Comment: @Welly: you're right. I've updated my answer, try it now. It should work, I've tried that on my side.

Comment: @Welly Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: How can I mark the answer as accepted? Fyi, I'm a new stackoverflow user.

Comment: Ok, i have read stackoverflow user guide to mark accepted the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I also observed that if we don't give ***"dialect=unix"*** in "Library     DataDriver      file=resources/logindata2.csv    endocing=uft_8", then we get error

Variable '${username}' not found.
or
Variable '${password}' not found.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Adding dialect=excel worked for me. Current using robotframework-datadriver==0.2.7 and robotframework 3.1.2.